# Generating PDF report : jFreeChart and DynamicReports

Tags: java, jfreechart, dynamic-reports

I need to generate a report as shown below:

[image]

I have designed a GUI using swing in NetBeans to enter the details:

[image]

The Plot I have generated using jFreeChart:

```
  JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
"Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
"Pounds(lb)", // domain axis label
"Movement(inch)", // range axis label
dataset, // data
PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
false, // include legend
true, // tooltips
false // urls
);
```

OutPut:

[image]

I was searching the internet and read that I can use iText or JasperReports or DynamicReports (Based on Jasper Report)

http://www.dynamicreports.org/getting_started.html#step9

I found using Dynamic Reports easier. My question is- can i use DynamicReports for my purpose (I suppose- yes looking at the sample reports) and if yes then how do I export my jFreeChart to the report.

Please help as I do not have much time left to complete this project.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can create the chart directly in DynamicReports instead of JFreeChart.  Use the DynamicReports XYLineChartReport component to do this.  See the example code at http://www.dynamicreports.org/examples/xylinechartreport.html.

If you want to use the JFreeChart output, export the chart to an image and then include that image in the report using `cmp.image()`:

```
// Create the chart.
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYLineChart(
    "Hysteresis Plot", // chart title
    "Pounds(lb)", // domain axis label
    "Movement(inch)", // range axis label
    dataset, // data
    PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, // orientation
    false, // include legend
    true, // tooltips
    false // urls
);

// Export the chart to an image.
BufferedImage image = chart.createBufferedImage( 300, 300);

report()
    .title(cmp.text("XYZ HOSPITAL"))
    .columns(fieldNameColumn, fieldValueColumn)
    .summary(
        cmp.verticalList()
            .add(cmp.text("HYSTERISIS PLOT"))
            .add(cmp.text("A brief description of what this plot signifies"))
            .add(cmp.image(image))  // Add the exported chart image to the report.
            .add(cmp.text("REMARKS"))
    )
    .setDataSource(createDataSource())
    .toPDF(outputStream);
```

Comment: I have already created as shown in above figure to shown on the gui panel, now I just need to export it to the report.

Comment: Edited answer to add example using JFreeChart.

Comment: I searched that- I can save the jFreeChart as .png or .jpeg image then include it in the report and then can delete the image file . So basically the image file serves as a temp file. I was wondering if I can directly export as iText does?